# eliminar un registro despues de aceptar en mensaje de confirmacion de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

tengo una funcion para eliminar un registro de mi BD pero antes de eliminar el registro muestro un mensaje de confirmacion
el problema es que el mensaje no se muestra, se va directamente a mi funcion que hace la eliminacion de la BD, ¿Que debo hacer
para que pueda mostrar el mensaje de confirmacion y si da clic en aceptar ahora si pase a la funcion que elimina

```js
    $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        

            EliminarFormula($(e.relatedTarget).data().id);
   
    });
    
    
    function Eliminar(idElimina) {
     
    var url = "/Validador/Eliminar";
    //var url = "#";
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("idElimina", idElimina);

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: url,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success === true) {

                messageOK('Aviso', data.Mensaje);
            }
            else {

                messageOK('Aviso', data.Mensaje);

            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorthrow) {

        }

    });
}
```

```html
<a data-id="123" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>X</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que estás bindeando la llamada a la función de eliminación en el evento `show.bs.modal` que es el evento que se lanza al mostrar la ventana.

No sé cuál es tu HTML pero entiendo que será algo parecido a lo que te pongo a continuación. En ese caso debes bindear la función de eliminación al click del botón "Ok" (clase `.btn-ok`) de la ventana modal:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal',function(){
      $('.btn-ok').click(function(){
         console.log("Llamamos a la función de eliminación");
        });
    });
      
        $('#go').click(function()
        {
            $('#confirm-delete').modal('show');
           
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar registro</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>¿Estás seguro de eliminar el registro?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" data-dismiss="modal">Sí</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">No
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button id="go">
    X
    </button>
```